# how to make firestore data online only?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make the user to access firestore data in my flutter app only when they are online.

I am expecting that firestore data can't stored in cache memory, so tha tthe user only gets the data when they are online.

Comment: u mean It should be not store in firebase if network is not available?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your question is just asking how to disable any persistence to confirm that your app is only receiving up-to-date data. You can configure that with your Firebase settings. Below is a snippet of code from the documentation.

```
// Apple and Android
db.settings = const Settings(persistenceEnabled: true);

// Web
await db
    .enablePersistence(const PersistenceSettings(synchronizeTabs: true));
```

More information can be found on the [Access data offline documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#dart)

Answer (score 1):

you can check the internet by using `connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2` package
and with this package u can apply ur logic regarding connectivity...

Answer (score 1):

you can check the internet by using [connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package
so you can disable delete button if there is no internet

Your code will be like this:

```
YourAppState{
    ConnectivityResult _connectionStatus = ConnectivityResult.none;
    final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
    late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _connectivitySubscription_connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);
  }

   Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
     setState(() {
       _connectionStatus = result;
     });
      if (_connectionStatus.toString() == "ConnectivityResult.none") {
         navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
        }
    }
```

}

Then up your widget write this condition

```
if(_connectionStatus.toString() != "ConnectivityResult.none")
```

now if there is no internet connection the widget will not appear